# Compiling Java classes with dependencies using javac and no jars

Tags: java, compilation, javac

I've been searching for a solution to a problem I'm experiencing for compiling 2 classes. One dependent on the other using the javac command. I keep seeing examples using jars. But I don't have jars. I don't know if I need jars or packages but this is a really simple 2 classes example: I keep getting an error claiming the following:

> cannot find symbol Calculator calc = new Calculator();

```
// file name: Calculator.java

public class Calculator {

    int calc (int var1, int var2) {  
        return var1*var2;
    }

}
```

The main method is in the below class that uses the calculator.

```
// file name: Main.java

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
        int value = calculator.calc(4, 6);
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

In the command prompt I navigate over to the folder where these classes exist and run javac as below:

```
cd Desktop/program
javac Calculator.java # Runs fine..
javac *.java # Shows ERROR as explained above

javac -cp .;/Users/paydie/Desktop/program/Calculator.clss Main.java # same error
```

Comment: 1. Your code doesn't compile change `value` to `result` in main. 2. Are you doing this in the same directory?

Comment: That was a typo and I fixed it. It still is not able to locate the Calculator class

Comment: Are the files in the same directory?

Comment: yes they are. On my desktop in the folder called example

Comment: Another thing: the -cp command should not take a file with a clss extension.

Comment: What should it take? besides a jar?

Comment: it should have directories.  One other thing, do you have a CLASSPATH environment variable set?

Answer (score 0):

If the files are in the same directory and the typo is corrected this should work:

Clean any classes out of the directory:

`del *.class`

Compile the files:

`javac *.java`

Run the Main.main:

`java Main`

The result should be `24`.